# How do you update the wsdl in a Eclipse Web Service Client project?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, service

I have an Eclipse web service client with a WCF service that I am calling functions from.  The WCF service has changed and I need to update the wsdl in my eclipse project without losing all of my code.  I haven't been able to find anything on google, mostly just tutorials on how to create client programs.  Does anybody know how to refresh/update that wsdl in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say that the exposed methods have changed(Its parameters and their data types) ? 
If yes, the wsdl can be re generated using the codegen JAVA2WSDL(plugin in eclipse).

Comment: Correct, there are also new methods that I have added.

Comment: I dont know if there is any means of refreshing the wsdl without the code getting changed. All I can suggest from my exp is that you can re generate the wsdl for the new exposed methods from Axis Codegen plugin(you just need to specify the path to the class files)